# Unable to find nested property using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I don't understand why this is returning null.

```
dg.Depth = 3
```

My object looks like this

[image]

and this is returning null??

```
var x = dg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LeafPosition == dg.Depth);
```

Is my understanding wrong that LINQ would do this search recursively?

Comment: Can you post your model for better understanding

Comment: if i understanding you will try Get LeafPosition from Children or so... ( Children Count = 0 and you Query cant get LeafPosition from Children Count = 0 ) Count = 0 => return Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like data structure wasn't designed for search of nested levels.

You can introduce a method for `GroupLeafNode` class

```
public class GroupLeafNode 
{
    public IEnumerable<GroupLeafNode> FindBy(int depth)
    {
        if (LeafPosition == depth)
        {
            yield return this;
        }

        return Children.SelectMany(node => node.FindBy(depth));
    }
}

// Usage

var result = 
    dg.Children.SelectMany(node => node.FindBy(dg.Depth)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, LINQ will not search recursively, you will need to flatten the nested collections somehow. `dg.Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LeafPosition == dg.Depth)` will search only the `Children` collection of `dg` not the descendants.

To search second level you can do something like this:

```
var secondLevelx = dg.Children
    .SelectMany(x => x.Children)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.LeafPosition == dg.Depth);
```

For third and so on you can add more chained `SelectMany` calls.